# Inequality in Sobolev spaces: does it hold?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$ and let $1\leq p < n$. Consider
$$ X = W_{0}^{1, p}(\Omega)\cap L^{\infty}(\Omega).$$
Let $u\in X$ and $l> p^{\ast}$. Does the inequality
$$\Vert u\Vert_{\infty}^{l-p} \Vert u\Vert_{W_0^{1,p}}^p \leq\Vert u\Vert_{X}^l$$
hold? Could anyone explain me why?
I tried by using Holder inequality but I didn’t solve the problem.
Could anyone please help?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the norm on the intersection the maximum of the norms of both spaces? And is $p^\ast$ the exponent that appears in the GNS inequality?

Comment: The norm on the intersection is given by $\Vert u\Vert_X = \Vert u\Vert_{W_0^{1,p}} + \Vert u\Vert_{\infty}$ and $p^{\ast}$ is the critical exponent for the Sobolev embedding, i.e. $p^{\ast} =\frac{np}{n-p}$.

Comment: Isn't it trivial then? Just use $\lVert u\rVert_\infty,\lVert u\rVert_{W^{1,p}}\leq \lVert u\rVert_X$.

Comment: Thank you @MaoWao, it was really trivial, I am sorry for my trivial question. Thanks again.